# SVG Path error in Chrome 78.0.3904.87 x64 (Debian 9.11)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

I have the following error in Chrome console when I add a SVG `<path>` with Javascript :

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "Z".
```

This error doesn't happen in Firefox Quantum 60.9.0esr.

Environment :

- Chrome 78.0.3904.87 x64
- Debian 9.11 x64

The `<path>` output build with Javascript is the following, as you can see the `M` and `Z` commands are present :

```
<path d="M6.536901088169657 96.77946103732506 16.19861537388391 96.77946103732506 M16.19861537388391 96.77946103732506 19.41918680245533 109.66174675161074 M19.41918680245533 109.66174675161074 38.74261537388389 132.2057467516106 M38.74261537388389 132.2057467516106 48.404329659598204 161.19088960875342 M48.404329659598204 161.19088960875342 67.72775823102677 190.17603246589647 M67.72775823102677 190.17603246589647 90.27175823102675 228.82288960875348 M90.27175823102675 228.82288960875348 112.81575823102673 264.24917532303925 M112.81575823102673 264.24917532303925 132.13918680245536 296.45488960875355 M132.13918680245536 296.45488960875355 148.2420439453125 322.2194610373249 M148.2420439453125 322.2194610373249 164.34490108816965 335.1017467516107 M164.34490108816965 335.1017467516107 177.22718680245532 344.763461037325 M177.22718680245532 344.763461037325 180.4477582310268 351.20460389446794 M180.4477582310268 351.20460389446794 186.88890108816963 351.20460389446794 M186.88890108816963 351.20460389446794 190.1094725167411 351.20460389446794 M190.1094725167411 351.20460389446794 193.33004394531247 351.20460389446794 M193.33004394531247 351.20460389446794 196.550615373884 351.20460389446794 M196.550615373884 351.20460389446794 202.99175823102672 351.20460389446794 M202.99175823102672 351.20460389446794 209.43290108816967 347.98403246589646 M209.43290108816967 347.98403246589646 212.65347251674115 341.5428896087535 M212.65347251674115 341.5428896087535 225.53575823102682 328.6606038944677 M225.53575823102682 328.6606038944677 235.19747251674102 325.44003246589625 M235.19747251674102 325.44003246589625 248.0797582310267 322.2194610373249 M248.0797582310267 322.2194610373249 257.7414725167411 315.77831818018217 M257.7414725167411 315.77831818018217 267.4031868024553 309.3371753230392 M267.4031868024553 309.3371753230392 280.285472516741 299.675461037325 M280.285472516741 299.675461037325 289.9471868024554 290.0137467516106 M289.9471868024554 290.0137467516106 296.3883296595981 283.5726038944679 M296.3883296595981 283.5726038944679 302.8294725167411 277.1314610373249 M302.8294725167411 277.1314610373249 309.270615373884 270.6903181801822 M309.270615373884 270.6903181801822 312.4911868024553 261.0286038944678 M312.4911868024553 261.0286038944678 312.4911868024553 254.58746103732506 M312.4911868024553 254.58746103732506 315.71175823102675 241.70517532303916 M315.71175823102675 241.70517532303916 315.71175823102675 232.04346103732496 M315.71175823102675 232.04346103732496 315.71175823102675 219.1611753230393 M315.71175823102675 219.1611753230393 315.71175823102675 206.27888960875362 M315.71175823102675 206.27888960875362 315.71175823102675 193.39660389446794 M315.71175823102675 193.39660389446794 309.270615373884 186.955461037325 M309.270615373884 186.955461037325 309.270615373884 180.51431818018204 M309.270615373884 180.51431818018204 302.8294725167411 174.07317532303932 M302.8294725167411 174.07317532303932 296.3883296595981 174.07317532303932 M296.3883296595981 174.07317532303932 293.1677582310269 174.07317532303932 M293.1677582310269 174.07317532303932 283.50604394531246 174.07317532303932 M283.50604394531246 174.07317532303932 273.84432965959826 174.07317532303932 M273.84432965959826 174.07317532303932 270.6237582310268 174.07317532303932 M270.6237582310268 174.07317532303932 260.9620439453126 183.73488960875352 M260.9620439453126 183.73488960875352 254.52090108816964 193.39660389446794 M254.52090108816964 193.39660389446794 254.52090108816964 209.49946103732486 M254.52090108816964 209.49946103732486 251.30032965959816 222.38174675161076 M251.30032965959816 222.38174675161076 251.30032965959816 241.70517532303916 M251.30032965959816 241.70517532303916 251.30032965959816 257.8080324658963 M251.30032965959816 257.8080324658963 251.30032965959816 277.1314610373249 M251.30032965959816 277.1314610373249 251.30032965959816 290.0137467516106 M251.30032965959816 290.0137467516106 254.52090108816964 293.2343181801821 M254.52090108816964 293.2343181801821 257.7414725167411 302.8960324658965 M257.7414725167411 302.8960324658965 267.4031868024553 302.8960324658965 M267.4031868024553 302.8960324658965 270.6237582310268 302.8960324658965 M270.6237582310268 302.8960324658965 277.06490108816973 290.0137467516106 M277.06490108816973 290.0137467516106 289.9471868024554 270.6903181801822 M289.9471868024554 270.6903181801822 309.270615373884 251.36688960875358 M309.270615373884 251.36688960875358 325.3734725167412 225.602318180182 M325.3734725167412 225.602318180182 338.25575823102685 209.49946103732486 M338.25575823102685 209.49946103732486 357.57918680245547 186.955461037325 M357.57918680245547 186.955461037325 380.12318680245534 157.97031818018218 M380.12318680245534 157.97031818018218 393.005472516741 138.64688960875355 M393.005472516741 138.64688960875355 402.6671868024552 128.98517532303913 M402.6671868024552 128.98517532303913 412.32890108816963 116.10288960875346 M412.32890108816963 116.10288960875346 409.10832965959816 112.88231818018198 M409.10832965959816 112.88231818018198 396.2260439453125 125.76460389446788 M396.2260439453125 125.76460389446788 383.3437582310268 148.30860389446775 M383.3437582310268 148.30860389446775 367.24090108816966 180.51431818018204 M367.24090108816966 180.51431818018204 338.25575823102685 228.82288960875348 M338.25575823102685 228.82288960875348 309.270615373884 277.1314610373249 M309.270615373884 277.1314610373249 286.72661537388393 315.77831818018217 M286.72661537388393 315.77831818018217 286.72661537388393 351.20460389446794 M286.72661537388393 351.20460389446794 286.72661537388393 370.52803246589633 M286.72661537388393 370.52803246589633 286.72661537388393 380.18974675161076 M286.72661537388393 380.18974675161076 286.72661537388393 383.4103181801818Z" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="4" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" aria-hidden="true" transform="scale(1) rotate(0) translate(0, 0)"></path>
```

It is wrapped in the following parent SVG container :

```
<svg:svg version="1.1" width="797.1999999999999px" height="1127.1999999999998px" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 797.1999999999999 1127.1999999999998" style="width: 247px; height: 350px; transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);"></svg:svg>
```

How to get rid of this error? Am I doing something wrong or is it some Chrome bug?

Comment: The path you are using is a funny one. You have only M commands and no L commands. However "If a moveto is followed by multiple pairs of coordinates, the subsequent pairs are treated as implicit lineto commands" Maybe it's a Debian thing. Try adding the missing L commands. The z command you are using at the end of the path is pointless since is "closing" a straight line.

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks for pointing that out. Changing the Javascript that builds the path fixed it.